# How to Center and make full width youtube iframe in responsive view?

Tags: css

I have some iframe youtube video on my website. In esponsive view, they are not centered and not full width.

You can see it there: 
http://spitzpomeranian.com/fr

Here is the screenshot of my problem

http://prntscr.com/bxn4pe

I tried to edit the css code in jconsole but I couldn't find the solution.

Is there any expert who can tell me how to center and make full width the videos?

Answer (score 1):

You can override width of the iframe in css

```
iframe{ /*use class or id for the iframe*/
width:100%!important;
height:auto!important;
}
```

In your case there are some other div that needs to be given 100% width

```
.resp_video{
width:100%;
}
.wrap_video{
width:100%; /*adjust the margin to make the div fit inside the page without horizontal scrollbar*/
}
```

You the use above code within your **responsive @media query**

Answer (score 0):

See [Fluid Width YouTube Videos](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/)
This solution uses jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think once you have the video going down you can use media query to center them both by making the width 100%.